# Angular lazy routes children aren't being found

Tags: angular, angular-ui-router

I just started working on learning angular routes with lazy loading and loading components in auxiliary router-outlets. Initially working with /(aux-name:path) to add to the auxiliary route. This worked great. I am trying to modify to use a simple path and the auxiliary router-outlet being defined in the respective routing.module.

In my app-router.component.ts

```
const rootRoutes: Routes = [
  {
    path: '', 
    loadChildren: () => import('./login/login.module').then(m => m.LoginModule),
    data: {
      title: 'Mako Reservations, LLC' 
    }
  },
  { 
    path: 'admin',
    loadChildren: () => import('./landing-page/landing-page.module').then(m => m.LandingPageModule),
  },
```

Nothing fancy. The landing-page will show. The landing page has an auxiliary route. When using the url to include (sidebar:) it worked as expected. Some of the lazy loaded modules' components work but the child paths in those routes cannot be found.

landing-page-routing.module.ts

```
const landingRoutes: Routes = [
    {
        path: "",
        component: LandingPageComponent,
        children: [
            {
                path: "dashboard",
                loadChildren: () => import('./dashboard/dashboard.module').then(m => m.DashboardModule),
            },



            {
                path: "accounts",
                pathMatch: 'full',
                loadChildren: () => import('../account/accounts.module').then(m => m.AccountModule)
            },
            {
                path: "account",
                pathMatch: 'full',
                loadChildren: () => import('../account/accounts.module').then(m => m.AccountModule)
            },
        ]
    },
    {
        path: '**',
        component: PageNotFoundComponent
    },
];

@NgModule({
  imports: [CommonModule, RouterModule.forChild(landingRoutes)],
  exports: [RouterModule]
})
export class LandingPageRoutingModule { }
```

There are two paths to the account module. This was chosen as as logically I could view multiple accounts or edit or create a single account. No other purpose other than to allow two different paths to be used to access the same components.

In the account-routing.module.ts, I have the following routes.

```
const accountRoutes: Routes = [
    {
        path: "",
        component: ManageAccountsComponent,
        outlet: 'sidebar',
        children: [
            {
                path: "create",
                pathMatch: 'full',
                component: EditAccountComponent,
                outlet: 'sidebar',
            },
            {
                path: "id/:id",
                pathMatch: 'full',
                component: EditAccountComponent,
                outlet: 'sidebar',
            },
        ]
    },
    {
        path: '**',
        component: EditAccountComponent,
        outlet: 'sidebar',
    },
];
```

When I run locally, I can access the landing-page (localhost:4200/admin) and I can click the link to get to the accounts page (localhost:4200/admin/accounts).

Problem is when I attempt to edit an account (http://localhost:4200/admin/account/id/5), I am directed to the page not found component. I have attempted to modify the pathMatch.

Do you have any idea on what I may be doing wrong with my lazy loaded paths?

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 0):

I am guessing you wanted to load in the main router but copied in the sidebar outlet.

```
        path: "",
        component: ManageAccountsComponent,
        outlet: 'sidebar', <--- prorabably just remove this.
        children: [
```

else i cannot see ouw you would reach the id/:id i guess its the same for create ?

Comment: Once I login, I am viewing my landing page within the primary route. All subsequent components should be shown within the aux router (sidebar). The landing page is the sole user for the main router for a logged in user.

When using http://localhost:4200/admin/(sidebar:accounts/create) it is loaded in the sidebar router as expected. Problem is when I attempt to go to http://localhost:4200/admin/accounts/create it is redirected to the landing page routing's page not found and not the accounts routing page not found.

Answer (score 0):

I believe it wraps around the pathMatch as noted by Henrik. When attempting to make the change suggested didn't work, I reordered the child routes to be siblings BUT I also had to put the **path: ''** as the last element prior to the '**'. It then is opening the correct components on the routes as expected.

From

```
const accountRoutes: Routes = [
    {
        path: "",
        component: ManageAccountsComponent,
        children: [
            {
                path: "create",
                component: ManageCouponsComponent,
            },
            {
                path: "id/:id",
                component: ManageCouponsComponent,
            },
        ],
    },
    {
        path: '**',
        // component: ManageCouponsComponent
        redirectTo: '/login'
    }
];
```

To:

```
const accountRoutes: Routes = [
    {
        path: "create",
        component: EditAccountComponent,
    },
    {
        path: "id/:id",
        component: EditAccountComponent,
    },
    {
        path: "",
        component: ManageAccountsComponent,
    },
    {
        path: '**',
        // component: ManageCouponsComponent
        redirectTo: '/login'
    }
];
```