Angular 18 Routing/URL
I am currently exploring angular 18 and noticed that sometimes when the app is routed to a component and not on the homepage;

If I refresh, it takes me back to the home page instead of reloading the current route. For example I am on this route "example.com/account/settings" and refresh, it takes me back to "example.com" and gives me a blank screen.

When on a route and I click on another route, it reloads the current route instead of loading the new route. For example, I am on this route "example.com/account/settings" and click on another route "example.com/pricing". It reloads the current route "example.com/account/settings" and gives me a blank screen.


It may be that there are breaking changes I am not aware of and I haven't seen anything online related to the issue I am having.
Any idea on what the issue might be?
NB: Some of my routes are lazy loaded and this same approach works fine on Angular 16 and below.
My component HTML
<a href="javascript:;" routerLink="pricing"><i class='bx bx-radio-circle'></i>

app component HTML
<router-outlet />

My Routing Module
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { RouterModule, Routes } from '@angular/router';
import { PRICING_COMPONENT } from './pricing/pricing.component';
import { DASHBOARD_COMPONENT } from './dashboard/dashboard.component';

const routes: Routes = [
  {path: '', component: DASHBOARD_COMPONENT },
  {path: 'pricing', component: PRICING_COMPONENT },
  {
    path: 'account',
    // canActivate: [AuthGuard, SessionGuard, VerificationGuard],
    loadChildren: () => import('./lazy-loaded-account/lazy-loaded-account.module').then(
      module => module.LAZY_LOADED_ACCOUNT_MODULE
    )
  }
];

@NgModule({
  imports: [RouterModule.forRoot(routes)],
  exports: [RouterModule]
})
export class AppRoutingModule { }

My Lazy Loaded Routing file
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { RouterModule, Routes } from '@angular/router';
import { PROFILE_COMPONENT } from './profile/profile.component';
import { SETTINGS_COMPONENT } from './settings/settings.component';

const routes: Routes = [
  {path: 'profile', component: PROFILE_COMPONENT},
  {path: 'settings', component: SETTINGS_COMPONENT},
];

@NgModule({
  imports: [RouterModule.forChild(routes)],
  exports: [RouterModule]
})
export class LAZY_LOADED_ACCOUNT_ROUTING_MODULE { }


<a href="javascript:;" routerLink="pricing"> This looks really strange. Why did you implement the link that way?

@GreatEfue please share the routing for account/settings, also try removing the href="javascript:;" it maybe be causing the reload

@JSONDerulo Whenever I use the anchor element, I have always implemented angular route that way since Angular 6. I may be wrong, kindly advise.

Why? I have never seen this. The docs have never recommended this. https://angular.dev/guide/routing/router-reference#router-links

@NarenMurali The route 'account/settings' is lazy loaded so in the main routing file, I have 'account' as the first URL segment which loads the lazy loaded module and in the lazy loaded routing file, I have 'settings' as the last URL segment which loads the actual settings component.

@GreatEfue You have shared the main routing file, but there is no account which lazy loads the account module actually. Please share all the routing details.

@NarenMurali What I have shared has some edits in the component name and routes because of security reasons but I will share what you have requested. I am currently not on my computer. Thanks

@JSONDerulo I have gone through the document link you shared and you seems to be correct. I will update and revert. Thanks

@NarenMurali I have updated the question to include the lazy loaded routing file and update the main routing file. Sorry for the delay.

I recommend you to check this (https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74756904/angular-lazy-routes-children-arent-being-found) and add redirectTo inside your main routing. Also, you need to have a route inside of every routing of empty string '', to redirect to that route when you refresh.

Thank you all,
The issue emanated from putting href and routerLink together as highlighted below.
<a href="javascript:;" routerLink="pricing">

I changed to the below and the issue was resolved.
<a routerLink="pricing">

@JSON Derulo was right
Reference https://angular.dev/guide/routing/router-reference#router-links
